# Calculating percentages for 10 or more images in a CSS3 slideshow

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I am trying to animate a series of 10 images in a timed looping slideshow. The slideshow is already working... sort of. Being very new to CSS3, and even after searching Google all day, I have not found the answer to this concern.

My first issue lies with the timing of each image. I already have a div for each of the 10 images AND have written individual rules for each image in my CSS (as indicated by the 'etc....' below).

I am not sure how I am supposed to calculate the percentages for @keyframe animations according to how many images you are using. I have provided an example below:

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim_slides {
0% { opacity:0; }
6% { opacity:1; }
24% { opacity:1; }
30% { opacity:0; }
100% { opacity:0;}
}

.slides ul  li:nth-child(2), .slides ul  li:nth-child(2) div {
-webkit-animation-delay: 8.0s;
-moz-animation-delay: 8.0s;}

.slides ul  li:nth-child(3), .slides ul  li:nth-child(3) div {
-webkit-animation-delay: 16.0s;
-moz-animation-delay: 16.0s;}

.slides ul  li:nth-child(4), .slides ul  li:nth-child(4) div {
-webkit-animation-delay: 24.0s;
-moz-animation-delay: 24.0s;}

.slides ul  li:nth-child(5), .slides ul  li:nth-child(5) div {
-webkit-animation-delay: 32.0s;
-moz-animation-delay: 32.0s;}

etc....
```

I included the .slides info really just as a reference, since what I am most concerned with is the percentages.

Most of the tutorials I have found for CSS3 animations only use between 3-6 images, and the percentages are set specifically for that amount. Since I am using 10 images, the percentages no longer correlate, it seems.

Second, I am uncertain how the duration of the animation is affected when you have more than the (apparently) standard 3-6 images.

```
.slides ul li {
opacity:0;
position:absolute;
top:0;

/* css3 animation */
-webkit-animation-name: anim_slides;
-webkit-animation-duration: 80.0s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

-moz-animation-name: anim_slides;
-moz-animation-duration: 80.0s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-direction: normal;
-moz-animation-delay: 0;
-moz-animation-play-state: running;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
```

As you can see, the animation-duration is set to 80.0s. Honestly, I am not even sure if that is correct.

Can anyone help me out? All I need really is an explanation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you calculate the percentages depends on how exactly want the transition to work.

When you set

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim_slides {
    0% { opacity:0; }
    6% { opacity:1; }
    24% { opacity:1; }
    30% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:0;}
}
```

What you are saying is that there is a transition from 0 to 1 that takes 6% of the cycle, a period of 18% (24-6) where opacity = 1, and another transition from 1 to 0 for another 6%.

One way to set such a transition is that the transition "in" of an element overlaps the transition "out" of the prior element.

In this case, for 10 images, there will be 10 phases of full visibility and 10 transitions. 
So, the time for the sum of the 2 would be 10% (100% / 10). You can now asign this 10% as you want to full visibility and transitioning. if the ratio is 1 / 3, as was in your example, then it is 2.5% for transition and 7.5% for still image.

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim_slides {
    0% { opacity:0; }
    2.5% { opacity:1; }
    10% { opacity:1; }
    12.5% { opacity:0; }
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, both for your explanation and for solving my issues. :D

Comment: Thank you MiniRagnarok for your assistance. =)