# Text in the CSS slide overlaps

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to insert 4 lines of text in my slide with css. The effect works but when it arrives the third and fourth slides the texts overlap and do not change at the right times.

How can I correct this?

This is my code:

```css
.col-sm-12{width:100%;padding:15px;float:left;}

#textComAz .item-1, #textComAz .item-2, #textComAz .item-3, #textComAz .item-4 {position: absolute;display: block;top: 2em;width: 100%;font-size: 2em;animation-duration: 20s;animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;animation-iteration-count: infinite;text-align:center;}
#textComAz .item-1{animation-name: anim-1;}
#textComAz .item-2{animation-name: anim-2;}
#textComAz .item-3{animation-name: anim-3;}
#textComAz .item-4{animation-name: anim-4;}

@keyframes anim-1 {0%, 8.3% { left: -50%; opacity: 0; }8.3%,25% { left: 0%; opacity: 1; }33.33%, 100% { left: 25%; opacity: 0; }}

@keyframes anim-2 {0%, 33.33% { left: -50%; opacity: 0; }41.63%, 58.29% { left: 0%; opacity: 1; }66.66%, 100% { left: 25%; opacity: 0; }}

@keyframes anim-3 {0%, 55.55% { left: -50%; opacity: 0; }64.96%, 71.62% { left: 0%; opacity: 1; } 100% { left: 25%; opacity: 0; }}

@keyframes anim-4 {0%, 75.55% { left: -50%; opacity: 0; }84.96%, 91.62% { left: 0%; opacity: 1; }100% { left: 25%; opacity: 0; }}
```

```html
<div id="textComAz" class="col-sm-12">
<p class="item-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
<p class="item-2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium.</p>
<p class="item-3">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure.</p>

<p class="item-4">NEW TEXT HERE.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `%` into keyframe for render the result you need, i just change a little bit the `%` but you need to change it for **your** result.

```css
.col-sm-12 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
}

#textComAz .item-1,
#textComAz .item-2,
#textComAz .item-3,
#textComAz .item-4 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2em;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  text-align: center;
}

#textComAz .item-1 {
  animation-name: anim-1;
}

#textComAz .item-2 {
  animation-name: anim-2;
}

#textComAz .item-3 {
  animation-name: anim-3;
}

#textComAz .item-4 {
  animation-name: anim-4;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
  0%,
  8.3% {
    left: -50%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  8.3%,
  25% {
    left: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.33%,
  100% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
  0%,
  33.33% {
    left: -50%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  41.63%,
  58.29% {
    left: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66.66%,
  100% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
  0%,
   66.66% {
    left: -50%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  74.96%,
  83.26% {
    left: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  83.26%,
  100% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-4 {
  0%,
  83.26% {
    left: -50%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  91.56%,
  99.86% {
    left: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="textComAz" class="col-sm-12">
  <p class="item-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
  <p class="item-2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium.</p>
  <p class="item-3">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure.</p>

  <p class="item-4">NEW TEXT HERE.</p>
</div>
```

You can read:

- [Calculating percentages for 10 or more images in a CSS3 slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754462/calculating-percentages-for-10-or-more-images-in-a-css3-slideshow)